# TextToSpeech se demora en partir

Tags: java, android-studio

Al iniciar un `Activity` ejecuto en la función `onCreate` el siguiente código:

```
tts = new TextToSpeech(this, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onInit(int status)
    {
        if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS)
        {
            tts.setLanguage(singletonGame.locale);
            tts.speak(instruction, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
        }
    }
});
```

Pero hay un retraso en que empiece a sonar el audio, porque se demora.

Intente dejar el objeto `TextToSpeech` en una clase `Singleton` para tenerla pre-cargada antes y no esperar el retraso, pero me lanza un error, porque debo destruirla en cada escena que llame el objeto.

¿Alguien sabe alguna solución?

Actualización 1:

Hice una prueba y lo que se demora es esta línea en ejecutarse, porque entra rápido al `IF`

`tts.speak(instruction, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se demora porque la función `speak` tiene un `run` y espera un servicio, por eso.

Por lo cual la solución que encontré es colocar un mensaje que diga "Cargando..."

```
tts = new TextToSpeech(this, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onInit(int status)
    {
        if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS)
        {
            tts.setLanguage(singletonGame.locale);
            tts.speak(cs, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null,"idUnico");
        }
    }
});
```

Y le agrego las funciones cuando empieza y termina:

```
tts.setOnUtteranceProgressListener(new UtteranceProgressListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onStart (String utteranceId)
    {
        Log.d("tts_","empezando");
    }

    @Override
    public void onError (String utteranceId){ Log.d("tts_","error"); }

    @Override
    public void onDone (String utteranceId)
    {
        Log.d("tts_","listo");
    }

});
```